# How do I make my vb application run every 15 minutes and keeping webpage alive

Tags: vb.net

//I want to run this code every 15 minutes while keeping the webpage alive.

```
Private Async Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim y As Integer
    y = 0
    Do While y = 0

        Dim x As Integer
        For x = 0 To TextBox5.Text - 1 Step 1

            Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

            For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

                If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "renew" Then

                    webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
                    Await Task.Delay(4000)
                End If

            Next

            WebBrowser1.Navigate("*MYLINK*")

        Next
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This code currently works just needs the 15 minute cycle and keep alive function added. Thankyou in advance!!

Comment: This looks like VB not VBA. Revised tag accordingly.

Comment: Why do you need to "keep the webpage alive"?

Comment: because the webpage will time out of the login

Comment: Please add any further details in the body of the question... not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in a timer, and set the timer's interval to 900000. Just a suggestion :D

Dunno if it will work.

---

As an answer to your comment:

Add a timer in the Designer mode, go to it's properties and set the Interval to 900000. Then double-click the timer and do this code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

This code refreshes the site when the timer ticks. It tick every < interval > milliseconds.

But if the login time's out after exactly 15 minutes I recommend lowering the timer's Interval to like 840000. Which is 14 minutes.

Comment: I also have to keep it alive.

Comment: Also how would I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way Would Be Adding A Timer TO Your App And Setting it to enabled and the interval to 900000 = 15 mins

Comment: You do realize that that is the exact same thing I said, right?

Comment: yeah but he wanted 15 mins not 14 xD

Comment: Read the top of my question. I also explained why he should put it to 14. If the login times out after exactly 15 min there is a small chance that the Refresh code will fail to keep him logged in. That's why it's good to lower it. Besides, it was a recommendation... I already mentioned 900000 two times.